# Python to excel array broken into characters

Tags: python, arrays, excel, request

When I put the code into excel every character is spaced out. This causes Tuesday to look like T,u,e,s,d,a,y in excel. The goal would be to have each cell in excel to have its own word and not the character. There are many for loops and I struggle with finding an answer to this ongoing problem. Any ideas?

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
from openpyxl import Workbook

NMNorth2=[("Farmington"),("Gallup"),("Grants"),("Las_Vegas"),("Raton"),("Santa_Fe"), ("Taos"),("Tijeras"),("Tucumcari")]
NMNorth=[("NM", "Farmington"),("NM", "Gallup"),("NM", "Grants"),("NM", "Las_Vegas"),("NM", "Raton"),("NM", "Santa_Fe"), ("NM", "Taos"),("NM", "Tijeras"),("NM", "Tucumcari")]

wb = Workbook()
dest_filename = 'weather.xlsx'
ws1 = wb.active
ws1.title = "Weather"
for state, city in NMNorth:

r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/id/forecast/q/"+state+"/"+city+".json")

data = r.json()

forecast = data['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday']
for n in forecast:

    day = n['title']
    forecaststm = (n['fcttext'])
    columnVariable = 2
    for x in day:
        ws1.cell(row = 1, column = columnVariable).value = x
        columnVariable +=1

    for y in forecaststm:
        ws1.cell(row = 2, column = columnVariable).value = y
        columnVariable +=1


rowVariable = 2
ws1.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = "City"
for state in NMNorth2:
ws1.cell(row = rowVariable, column = 1).value = state
rowVariable +=1

wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Comment: Hi roganjosh,
I did print the items and they came out as words, but are now coming out as characters in excel.

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. Thank you.
You are more than welcome to put your answer in the answer section if you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that python treats strings as iterables. In other words, this bites you if you think you're iterating through a list of strings (or similar) and go one level too deep in nested `for` loops; the easiest way to identify this is to `print` what you're working with on each loop.

In your case, the below loop is taking each letter (`x`) in the day of the week (`day`), writing it to a column and then incrementing the column you're writing to (`columnVariable`):

```
for x in day:
    ws1.cell(row = 1, column = columnVariable).value = x
    columnVariable +=1
```

Aside, camelCase isn't standard Python, it's more common to use underscores e.g. `column_variable`. See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)